# How to log input and output into a text file in Python?

Tags: python, logging

Is there a way to save the program input and output to a text file? Let's have a really simple application and say I want to log the shell to a "log.txt" file.

```
What's your name?
Peter

How old are you?
35

Where are your from?
Germany

Hi Peter, you're 35 years old and you're from Germany!
```

I believe that the logging module could be the way but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: u can use logging to store input and output

Comment: You can use the logging module as answered previously, or check out these two posts to see various other ways to capture user input into a file: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61291251/9587457, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3011680/9587457

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation there is a [Basic Logging Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#basic-logging-tutorial).

A very simple example would be:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
logging.error('And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö')
```

That's the explanation:
First you import `logging`, and after that you configure it with `basicConfig` indicating the file that you want to save the log messages to.

Then, every time you want to add something to the log, you have to use the logging functions: `debug()`, `info()`, `warning()`, `error()` and `critical()`, that are named after the level or severity of the events they are used to track.